# REACT/MONGODB Having difficulty creating an "item" model that can upload an item with title, description, and images to mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am working on a website to add items of clothing and display them. My end goal is to be able to create an article of clothing with title, description, and multiple photos. Right now I am able to create an entry for the DB that holds the title and description, but the file is always either empty or no file at all uploads with the entry.

Here is my current setup.

Models > Item model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const itemSchema = new Schema({
   title: {type: String},
   description: {type: String},
   files: {type: String} <---I know I dont want this to be string but it wont let me select File of any kind
     
}, {
timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

AdditemForm

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


import * as itemsService from '../../utilities/items-service'

export default function AddItemForm() {

    const [fullItem, setFullItem] = useState({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        file: ''
      });
    
      function handleChange(evt) {
        setFullItem({ ...fullItem, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
      }
    
      async function handleSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/api/items', fullItem)
      .then(response => {
        // Handle the response (e.g., show success message, update UI, etc.)
        console.log('Item uploaded successfully:', response.data);
        })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle errors (e.g., show error message, etc.)
        console.error('Error uploading item:', error);
        });
      };


    return (
      <>
        <div>This is the AddItemForm page</div>

        <div className="form-container">
            <form autoComplete="off" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Title: </label>
                <input type="text" name="title" value={fullItem.title} onChange={handleChange} required />
                <label>Description: </label>
                <input type="text" name="description" value={fullItem.description} onChange={handleChange} required />
                <label>File: </label>
                <input type="file" name="file" value={fullItem.file} onChange={handleChange} required />
                <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
      </>
    )
}
```

Then my create function

```
async function create(req, res) {
  try{
    const createdItem = await Item.create(req.body);
    res.json(createdItem);

  }  catch(err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
    console.log(err)
    } 
}
```

I've been watching videos for a few days now and all the examples are super easy but aren't working for me.

From what I have seen, Multer is no longer working or at least I couldn't get it to play nice with my version of react.

I have also tried using formData to send the item to the DB but Mongo doesn't get any of the fields at all when I do that. This is the alternative additem page

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ItemUpload = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const handleTitleChange = (event) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleDescriptionChange = (event) => {
    setDescription(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleFileSelect = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedImage(file);
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('image', selectedImage);

    axios.post('/api/items', formData)
      .then(response => {
        // Handle the response (e.g., show success message, update UI, etc.)
        console.log('Item uploaded successfully:', response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle errors (e.g., show error message, etc.)
        console.error('Error uploading item:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
    
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Title" value={title} onChange={handleTitleChange} />
      <textarea placeholder="Description" value={description} onChange={handleDescriptionChange}></textarea>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileSelect} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
    </div>

    </>
  );
};

export default ItemUpload;
`
```

Also tried submitting the item this way

```
 async function handleSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const newFullItem = await itemsService.createItem(fullItem)
 }
```

calls

```
import * as itemsAPI from './items-api';



export async function createItem(itemData) {
    const newItem = await itemsAPI.createItemRequest(itemData);
    return newItem;
  }
```

calls

```
import sendRequest from "./send-request";
const BASE_URL = '/api/items';

export function createItemRequest(itemData) {
    const newItem = itemData
    return sendRequest(BASE_URL, 'POST', newItem);
}// send-request.js


export default async function sendRequest(url, method = 'GET', payload = null) {
    const options = { method };
    if (payload) {
      options.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
      options.body = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }
    const res = await fetch(url, options);
    // res.ok will be false if the status code set is not 2xx
    if (res.ok) return res.json();
    throw new Error('Bad Request');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use multer for single file upload. I'm sure you can decipher it and adapt to handle multiple images:

react component:

```
        import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
        import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
        import axios from 'axios'
        import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';
        
        const AdminDashboard = (props) => {
           ...
            const addShoe = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                // try {
                axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/shoes', shoe, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', }, })
                    .then((res) => {
                        setCount(count + 1)
                        setShoe({
                            name: "",
                            brand: "",
                            gender: "M",
                            price: 0,
                            discountedPrice: 0,
                            image: 0,
                            color: "",
                            size: 0,
                            description: ""
                        })
                        setErrors({})
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err)
                        setErrors({
                            name: err.response.data.error.errors?.name,
                            brand: err.response.data.error.errors?.brand,
                            gender: err.response.data.error.errors?.gender,
                            price: err.response.data.error.errors?.price,
                            discountedPrice: err.response.data.error.errors?.discountedPrice,
                            color: err.response.data.error.errors?.color,
                            size: err.response.data.error.errors?.size,
                            description: err.response.data.error.errors?.description,
                            image: err.response.data.error.errors?.image,
                            generic: err.response.data
                        })
                    })
                // }
                // catch (error) {
                //     console.error('Error uploading sneaker:', error);
                // }
            };
        
            const handleChange = (e) => {
                if (e.target.name === 'image') {
                    setShoe({ ...shoe, image: e.target.files[0] });
                } else {
                    setShoe({ ...shoe, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
                }
            };
        
            
            return (
                <div className='admin-container'>
                    <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Admin Dashboard</h2>
                    <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Shoe Creator</p>
                    <form className='admin-dash' onSubmit={addShoe}>
                        <div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                {errors?.generic ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.generic?.message}</p> : null}
                                <label>Name</label>
                                {errors?.name ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.name?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name' value={shoe.name} onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                <label>Brand</label>
                                {errors?.brand ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.brand?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input type="text" name="brand" placeholder='Brand' value={shoe.brand} onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                <label>Color</label>
                                {errors?.color ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.color?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input type="text" name="color" placeholder='Color' value={shoe.color} onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                <label>Description</label>
                                {errors?.description ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.description?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input type="text" name="description" placeholder='Description' value={shoe.description} onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                <label>Gender</label>
                                {errors?.gender ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.gender?.message}</p> : null}
                                <select style={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px' }} name="gender" id="gender" onChange={handleChange}>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Gender</option>
                                    <option value="M">M</option>
                                    <option value="F">F</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                <label>Size</label>
                                {errors?.size ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.size?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input type="number" name="size" value={shoe.size} placeholder='Shoe Size' onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                <label>Price</label>
                                {errors?.price ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.email?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input type="number" name="price" value={shoe.price} placeholder='Price' onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                <label>Discounted Price</label>
                                {errors?.discountedPrice ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.discountedPrice?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input type="number" placeholder='Discounted Price' name="discountedPrice" value={shoe.discountedPrice} onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-divs'>
                                {errors?.image ? <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors?.image?.message}</p> : null}
                                <input id="file-input" class="file-input-label" type="file" name="image" onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                            <button className='admin-btn' type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSearch} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <input className='search-sneaks' type="text" value={searchQuery} onChange={handleSearchInputChange} placeholder='Sneaker Searcher' />
                        <button className='search-btn' onClick={handleSearch}>Search</button>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
            )
        }
        
        export default AdminDashboard
```

Controller:

```
    const SneakerFinder = require('../models/sneakers.model')
    
    module.exports = {
    
        
        createSneaker: async (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.body)
            try {
                const { name, brand, gender, price, discountedPrice, color, size, description } = req.body;
                const image = req.file.filename;
    
                const sneaker = new SneakerFinder({ name, brand, gender, price, discountedPrice, color, size, description, image });
                console.log(sneaker)
                await sneaker.save();
    
                res.status(201).json({ message: 'Sneaker uploaded successfully!' });
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong creating a sneaker. Please ensure there is an image file', error: error });
            }
        },
        updateSneakerBody: async (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.body)
            try {
                console.log(req.body, "...", req.file)
                const { name, brand, gender, price, discountedPrice, color, size, description } = req.body
    
                const updatedSneaker = await SneakerFinder.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: req.params.id },
                    { name, brand, gender, price, discountedPrice, color, size, description },
                    { new: true },
                    { runValidators: true },
                )
    
                res.status(201).json({ message: '72 Sneaker body updated successfully!', sneaker: updatedSneaker })
                console.log("73", updatedSneaker)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("75 Something went wrong updating a shoe body", error)
                res.status(500).json({ message: '76 Error updating sneaker body', error: error })
            }
        },
    
        updateSneakerImage: async (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.body)
            try {
                console.log(req.body, "...", req.file)
                const image = req.file ? req.file.filename : null
    
                const updatedSneaker = await SneakerFinder.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: req.params.id },
                    { image },
                    { new: true }
                )
    
                res.status(201).json({ message: 'Sneaker image updated successfully!', sneaker: updatedSneaker })
                console.log(updatedSneaker)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong updating a shoe image", error)
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating sneaker image', error: error })
            }
        },
```

Route:

```
const uploadMiddleware = require('../middleware/multerMiddleware')
    const SneakerController = require("../controllers/sneakers.controller");
    
    module.exports = (app) => {
        app.get('/api/', SneakerController.index);
        app.get('/api/shoes', SneakerController.getAllSneakers);
        app.get('/api/shoes/:id', SneakerController.getOneSneaker);
        app.post('/api/shoes', uploadMiddleware.single('image'), SneakerController.createSneaker);
        app.put('/api/shoes/:id', SneakerController.updateSneakerBody);
        app.put('/api/shoes/:id/image', uploadMiddleware.single('image'), SneakerController.updateSneakerImage);
        app.delete('/api/shoes/:id', SneakerController.deleteSneaker);
    }
```

Middleware:

```
const multer = require("multer")

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "./public/uploads")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    const allowedFileTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/webp']
    if (allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
}

const uploadMiddleware = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 5000000 },
    fileFilter
})


module.exports = uploadMiddleware
```